# Write .msg file where input is mime Contents using chilkatDotNet.dll

Tags: c#, chilkat-email

I had mime contents of mail from gmail and now i want to create .msg file using chilkat and store that contents to .msg file.
How could i do that using chilkat any idea.

```
MsgFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, msgFileName + ".msg");
string mimeFile = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mail.MIMEContent);
           success = ObjEmail.SetFromMimeText(mimeFile);           
            if (success)
            {
                byte[] mimeContents = ObjEmail.GetMimeBinary();
                File.WriteAllBytes(MsgFilePath, mimeContents);
            }
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: it is creating .msg file but that file is not able to open with outlook it gives error message. Cannot start microsoft Office Outlook. Cannot open file: Subject.msg. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is it open in another program?

Comment: yes file exist, no is not open anywhere. I am opening the file which is currently generated programmatically.

Comment: How are you opening it? What is the full path to the file?